# Developing Simple Chat App in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have JDev 11.1.2.1.0.

Can anyone provide any references to develop a simple chat app?
I want it for:
Two PCs connected together over a LAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to add chat option to JDeveloper itself - then just install the Oracle TPC extension and you'll get it.

If you want to build a chat application with Oracle ADF - then using the Active Data Services is the way to implement auto refresh of the client.
Lucas built a nice example http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/jellema-googletalk-094343.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are building this for educational purposes then Shay's answer is correct. You can use ADF's ADS to do this. ADS abstracts away most of the complexities(polling vs push, etc).

However, if you really are trying to build some form of http chat application, then there are far better technologies to build it on than Oracle ADF. It does not mean that if you know how to wield a hammer that every thing you see is a nail. Try giving technologies like Node.js a look and see if it fits what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But then I read this: http://teddziuba.com/2011/10/node-js-is-cancer.html

Comment: Right and because Node.js is so sucky that is why Microsoft decided to include it as part of the windows 8 Windows Azure platform? The author is obviously trolling and you've just been trolled.

Comment: And here's some more: http://joshuakehn.com/2011/10/3/Diagnosis-No-Cancer.html Again, the right tool for the right job. ADF is great but it is hardly a tool for every job.